# HTML / Javascript in custom field textarea?

Tags: custom-field, javascript, html, text

Is there a filter for allowing HTML / Javascript into a custom field textarea? I'm using get_post_meta.

On the frontpage I want the HTML / Javascript to run, not to be displayed.

Comment: Can you give and example of what your trying to run or is it a general question ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is `esc_textarea()`.

Example:

```
<textarea><?php echo esc_textarea($whatever); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered an identical question earlier today [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57719/html-code-in-custom-field/57726#57726) which tackled the same issue. In the case where you don't want to use a plugin like that suggested by EarnestoDev, you can simply wrap the output of your `<textarea></textarea>` with PHP's [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function like so;

```
<textarea name="my_html">

      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?>

</textarea>
```

Regardless of whether its a `textarea` or an `input` field etc, you still need to wrap your input in `htmlspecialchars` to preserve your tags from being stripped.

Comment: Don't do that. Use the built in functions. The `esc_textarea()` function is what you want for this case. If he wanted to put something in an attribute (like the value field of an input tag), then he would use `esc_attr()` instead.

Comment: For a WP based function, yes `esc_textarea` is the API call you want to be making and what I should have said in context was `htmlspecialchars` which is what underpins `esc_textarea`. So to the OP, use `esc_textarea` instead, although using `htmlspecialchars` is perfectly valid PHP, its not the official API call, regardless of whether it'll do you no harm, at the very least you gain an insight to what `esc_textarea` is using, should you venture outside of the WP platform. `htmlentities` is also valid but its use-case dependent and probably not in context. @Otto I'll am mend my other answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Use the plugin I posted here:**
[Problem with <code> tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30904/problem-with-code-tag/31570#31570)
.

*Does what you need and more!*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there must be. When you save this into a custom field with a key let's say "test"...

```
<p>Test1</p><p>Test2</p>
```

You will get Test1Test2 when you run...

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test', true);
```

If I knew which filter was responsible for this I'd just do a remove_filter(). It would be great if there was a plugin that would show you what filters are registered to a specific hook. (There is a get_post_meta hook defined in /wp-includes/meta.php)

Comment: Actually, I believe the html is being stripped out before it's saved to the database, not while it is being pulled out.