# HTML code in Custom field

Tags: posts, custom-field, html, single

I'm using a custom field to display images in a slider on each post, but when I update the post after having entered the HTML code in the custom field, the code disappears. I'm assuming that there is some kind of filter that removes HTML code from custom fields when a post is saved. Is there a way to circumvent that without using a plugin?

Thanks!

Edit: The information is saved using the following code:

```
function save_details(){
    global $post;

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "ptime", $_POST["ptime"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "services", $_POST["services"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "tools", $_POST["tools"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "url", $_POST["url"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "images", $_POST["images"]);
}
```

You can find the complete functions.php code [here](http://pastebin.com/vi9UahNi) (Pastebin).

Comment: No, there is no such filter by default. How is the field saved? Add this information to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: Updated the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATED ANSWER

The correct function to use in context to WordPress and its intended API for this purpose is;

[`esc_textarea`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_textarea)

Thus your code would reflect something like this;

```
<textarea><?php echo esc_textarea($images);?></textarea>
```

Although `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` are valid to use, and even though `esc_textarea` wraps `htmlspecialchars` anyway, its more appropriate to use the official API call.

I've left my original answer below for reference purposes, however swap out the relevant functions as needed.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

In your snipped at Pastebin replace your `images_box` function with **(start of line 65)**;

```
function images_box($echo = FALSE){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $images = $custom["images"][0];
  ?>
  <textarea name="images" cols="100" rows="10">

      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($images); //Hi, I'm your input! ?> 

  </textarea>
  <?php
}
```

You were not echoing the value of your input between the `<textarea> ECHO INPUT HERE </textarea>` tags thus it appears you were not entering anything at all.

Also wrap your input with [htmlspecialchars](http://au.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Also `$city = $custom["images"][0];` should be `$images = $custom["images"][0];` **(line 68)**

Comment: I am using WPEngine that doesn't allow me to modify files in wp-includes directory. Is there any way to make it work using theme functions.php?